# Putting the table on the ground

Tags: geometry

If I have smooth surface (which is the graph of some function $f(x,y)$) , is it true that I have 4 points of plain square lying on this surface? And is it true that the length of the edge of such square may be any prescribed (if $f$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$)?

It's motivation may be found clear - can I put all four legs of the table on the any smooth ground?

Comment: Does your question translate like this?: "Does the curve $\gamma$, which is implicitly given by the inersection of $f$ and a plane, i.e. $f(x+y)=a x+by+c$, contain a point $(x_0,y_0)$, such that there is a vector $v$ and an orthogonal vector $w$, such that the other tree points of a square $(x_0,y_0)+v$ and $(x_0,y_0)+w$ and $(x_0,y_0)+v+w$ also lie on $\gamma$"?

Comment: Yes, but not "Does the curve", but "Is there exist"

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but note that a plane will in general cut the surface in a curve. The existence of squares in plane closed curves is discussed in the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem

Comment: If you can choose the plain as you wish, then the curve always exists. The "does there exist" part of the question is expressed with respect to the points.

Comment: Probably! See the discussion at http://www.qedcat.com/mathsnacks/table_turning.pdf .

Comment: @NickKidman And why does the curve with such properties exist?

Comment: The curve exists. If it has the properties relating to the square is the question. Anyway, I don't know the answer.

Comment: [Putting the table on the ground](http://youtu.be/gAYL5H46QnQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [The Wobbly Table Theorem](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math1a_2011/exhibits/wobblytable/). Or [How to stabilize a wobbly table](http://www.maa.org/devlin/devlin_02_07.html). Or [Turning the tables](http://www.qedcat.com/mathsnacks/table_turning.pdf). [Oops! just noticed @Ben already gave that last one in a comment]

Comment: So, as I understood, the problem is still opened in general. But for particular case (if $|f'| \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$) we hold the affirmative answer.